# OpenRefine SQLite addon

Tags: sqlite, openrefine

I just started to use OpenRefine and I wonder if there is any SQLite addon I could use.

I found a bunch of addons on [main download site](http://openrefine.org/download.html) but SQLite is not between them.
On the other hand there is a [pull](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/pull/2323) on github, that claims OpenRefine to support also SQLite. I tried to load data both from "This Computer" and "Database" option and I was not able to load SQLite in neither way.

And finally I found that there is a SQLite [directory](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/tree/master/extensions/database/src/com/google/refine/extension/database/sqlite) with JAVA files in the github extensions folder, that might be that above mentioned support. Is this meant to be installed the easy way (just create sqlite directory inside extensions and put all the *.java files there) or do I need some other trick to achieve support on SQLite within OpenRefine?

Comment: I found out about this SQLite connector [yesterday](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openrefine/04ZpGff65O0). It seems to be working from the feedback. It will be soon in version 3.4. To test it, you need to [compile the development version of Open Refine](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Building-OpenRefine-From-Source).

Comment: Great to have this option, thank you. I forgot to mention I am on version 3.3 and I would like to use it portable (which I presume works with built version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: The SQLite importer has been added to OpenRefine in version 3.4 (https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Changes-for-3.4) (as Ettore Rizza already mentioned)